# Caching of responses in HttpUrlConnection of android

Tags: android, caching, httpurlconnection, httpresponsecache

In my app , i have implemented HttpResponseCache to cache the responses so that it could be used instead of hitting the server. For a particular api , the server returns the header Cache-Control as no-cache;must-revalidate. It has the header ETag also. The problem is the response of this api is not cached. As a result each time I request the api , server returns 200.
Does no-cache,must-revalidate mean the response won't/shouldn't be cached ?

Please find below the request and response headers of the http request :

**Request Headers :**

GET  HTTP/1.1
User-Agent
Accept  application/json
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Cookie
Host
Connection  Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding gzip

**Response Headers :**

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control   no-cache, must-revalidate
ETag    "c683a0301c68c566fcc706f5cd82f1f8"
Content-Type    application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Content-Encoding    gzip
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Date    Mon, 24 Feb 2014 04:44:03 GMT

**Sending HTTP_GET request :**

```
URL url = new URL(this.url);
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setReadTimeout(timeout);
conn.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", this.userAgent);
conn.setUseCaches(true);
conn.setDefaultUseCaches(true);
conn.connect();
this.responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
this.extractResponseHeaders(conn.getHeaderFields());
InputStream inputStream = null;
if (this.responseCode >= 400 ) {
    inputStream = conn.getErrorStream();
} else {
    inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
}
try {
    if(null != inputStream){
        this.response   =  convertToString(inputStream);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and add important parts of your code, please.

Comment: Is there anything else that needs to be added ?

Comment: You don't have a java implementation?

Comment: Validate your findings with an HTTP debugging proxy like Charles. Apparently the HttpUrlConnection class will always return 200, regardless of whether it really got stuff from cache. Android 4.3 and up will add the Android-Response-Source header which will tell you whether it came from network or from cache.

Comment: What is **extractResponseHeaders**?

Comment: extractResponseHeaders() method iterates the header fields and stores them. A simple utility method we added in the class.